# Pytorch sum jacobian over inputs instead of outputs

Tags: python, pytorch, autograd, differentiation

Suppose I have a tensor `Y` that is (directly or indirectly) computed from a tensor `X`.

Normally when I apply `torch.autograd.grad(Y, X, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(Y))`, I get a gradient mask that is of the same shape as `X`. This mask is actually a weighted sum of the gradients of the elements of `Y` w.r.t. `X`.

**Is it possible to get a gradient mask of the same shape as `Y` instead, of which each element `mask[i][j]` is the sum of the gradients of `Y[i][j]` w.r.t. `X`?**

This is equivalent to summing the Jacobian `J(Y,X)` over the dimensions of `X` instead of over the dimensions of `Y`.

```py
>>> X = torch.eye(2)
>>> X.requires_grad_()
# X = [1 0]
#     [0 1]

>>> Y = torch.sum(X*X, dim=0)
# Y = [1, 1]

>>> torch.autograd.grad(Y, X, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(Y), retain_graph=True)
(tensor([[2., 0.],
         [0., 2.]]),)
```

But instead, I want:

```
# [2, 2]
```

because `torch.sum(torch.autograd.grad(Y[0],X)` equals `2` and `torch.sum(torch.autograd.grad(Y[1],X)` equals `2` as well.

It would be easy to calculate the Jacobian of `Y` w.r.t `X` and just sum over the dimensions of `X`. However, this is unfeasible memory-wise, as the functions I work with are neural networks with huge inputs and outputs.

Calculating each gradient separately (as I did in the comments) is also very undesirable because this is too slow.

Comment: How do you plan to use such resulting tensor? What is the mathematical reasoning behind it?

Comment: I am writing an LRP (layer relevance propagation) implementation that requires such a gradient mask. Anyway, I don’t think this operation is too far-fetched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run pytorch nightly, https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/10223 is partially implemented and should do what you want for most simple graphs.  You could also try using the trick described at https://j-towns.github.io/2017/06/12/A-new-trick.html .

EDIT: It looks like https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.autograd.functional.jvp.html#torch.autograd.functional.jvp implements the backwards of backwards trick for you.  So you could just do:

```
from torch.autograd.functional import jvp
X = torch.eye(2)                              
X.requires_grad_()                            
def build_Y(x):                               
    return torch.sum(x*x, dim=0)              
                                              
print(jvp(build_Y, X, torch.ones(X.shape))[1])
```